# Looping thorught array from JSON Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

[image]
This is the structure i made to decode the data i get from JSON

[image]
This the main code where i call the array result and tap into the tile and print out the title.
So my question is that result is array and it contain 14 items and in that 14 item there are 10 additional thing and title is one of them, so i want to print the title using FOR loop .
[image]
This the JSON file i am trying to parse

Comment: As [the Stack Overflow help docs say](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), “DO NOT use images of code.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could iterate over each of your items is using the `for X in Y` pattern.

```
for movie in decodeData.results {
  print(movie.title)
  print(movie.poster_path)
}
```

This pattern will iterate through each result in your array and assign it to the variable name you specify in the `for` statement.

You can learn more here: [Swift Control Flow](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html)